# Jmeter response-data giving "malformed request" error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing **performance testing** of an **e-commerce** website.

After **adding items to the cart** it is going to the **shipping page**
and **selecting the shipping address**,after that it is proceeding for **checkout**

In the **shipping page**,it is giving the following error in the response data

```
{"status":400,"message":"Malformed request","additional_error":""}
```

Request is going **POST and data as **JSON**

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know.

It is either a bug in your application or your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) you're sending with JMeter is really **malformed** and you need to fix it.

I would recommend capturing the same request to the **shipping page** originating from the real browser and JMeter using an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). The requests have to be **exactly the same** (apart from dynamic data which needs to be correlated). Given you send the same request you should receive the same response. Amend your request to 100% match what you see from the browser and the issue should go away.

In the 99% of cases REST requests are failing due to missing [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type) or similar (sometimes charset has to be specified as well). You can add this (and other) headers using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)